# Getting child window's handle C\C++

Tags: c++, c, winapi, parent-child, handle

I've tried searching here and on google, i ended up with the "GetDlgItem" method, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
HWND hwnd_Parent;
HWND hwnd_Child;

hwnd_Parent = FindWindow(NULL,"MyTitle");
hwnd_Child = GetDlgItem(hwnd, 0x00030756);
```

hwnd_Parent is ok (i even did some post message tests), but hwnd_Child is null.
So, the hex number you see was found through WinSpy++.

My system is Windows 7 64 bits, my IDE is Code Blocks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't confuse ID of a control with a handle.

Are you creating the windows in your own code or looking for them in another process? The reason I ask is CreateWindow allows you to set the control ID of child windows. Control ID is less likely to be dynamic and you can get that from Spy++ so you can then hard code the ID. No need to be using child handle found via SPy++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to know the ID of the window to use `GetDlgItem()`.  I suspect you are passing in an HWND that you got from Spy++.

It looks like you are poking around in another app because if it was your own app then you wouldn't need to call FindWindow, and you'd know the control ID.

Probably the easiest way to find this window, once you have got the top-level window from FindWindow, is to call [`EnumChildWindows()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: But it returns many leves, and none of them actually match the control id's from WinSpy++. I actually need to go 3 depths deep from the parent window.

Comment: @WoF_Angel You need to find something that identifies the window uniquely and then in the enum callback test for that. EnumChildWindows() descends through all the levels.

Comment: It is working with the ID's from WinSpy++, i will look into your tip, thank you. However, could you help me with getting the text from the elements of a list box in that window (it's the only one)?

Comment: List box is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775146(VS.85).aspx). Send it an `LB_GETCOUNT` message to find out how many items in the list. Then send it lots of `LB_GETTEXT` messages to read out the contents.

Comment: If the ID is changing then you may not be able to rely on it. You may find the window class could identify the window uniquely enough for your needs.

Comment: So far i'm getting a 0 as a return from "SendMessage(hwnd3, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0)". The list bos has expandable buttons and the class is called "TAMTreeView", maybe this is important?

Comment: Yes that's important. That's telling you that it's not a list box. It's a tree view. My guess is that it's a Delphi app. Do lots of the window classes begin with a capital `T`?

Comment: That's a Delphi app. You'll probably have some luck with that control by sending it [tree view messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch6etkw4.aspx) but they are much more complex than list box messages.

Comment: Do you think ill have an easier time with VB Script rather than C++ ?

Comment: No, that would be horrendous. I'd do it in Delphi because that's what I know. C++, Delphi, Python with win32api would be fine. VBscript would be terrible. I don't even know if it could be done!

Comment: Thanks. I will try a little more with C++. I'm getting a  " 'TVM_GETCOUNT' was not declared in this scope " error, do you know what header should i include?

Comment: The MSDN documentation tells you which header to include. In this case it is Commctrl.h

Comment: Yeah, i found that just before i could delete the comment, sorry, too noob. I'm getting a 0 as a return, ill try to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks dude, i'm still working my way, but i got TVM_GETCOUNT to work. I appreciate your effort in helping me, and sorry for the excessive noobness.

Answer (score 2):

`GetDlgItem` takes the ID of a control. `0x00030756` already looks like a handle, so what exactly are you trying to obtain?

```
hwnd_Child = (HWND)0x00030756;
```

(Of course, this is just an example. It doesn't help to hard-code handle values anyway.)

Comment: I noticed the control id changed once, and i updated it and it worked, but now it doesn't work again, im trying to figure out what is happening. Didn't even know they could change like that, i had to refresh WinSpy++

Comment: @WoF_Angel: WinSpy is just a debugging tool, don't use it to generate input for your program.

Comment: Ok, it maybe not the best choice but it's working for now, thanks. But hey, i need to get the contents of the only list box in my child window, could you help me with this? I'm trying to dig something about LB_GETCOUNT or LB_GETTEXT.

Comment: @WoF_Angel: You somehow need to identify that window, probably by its title or class. Hard-coding the handle won't work, because handle values will change everytime the window is created.

Answer (score 0):

Call GetDlgCtrlID first with the HWND to get the Control ID

```
int GetDlgCtrlID(HWND controlHandle);
```

then use the CWnd function GetDlgItem

```
CWnd* GetDlgItem(int controlID);
```